# prevent main window from scrolling when an item in the sidebare is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my web site [www.fsquare.be/diensten.html](http://www.fsquare.be/diensten.html) I have a sidebar, with links to the items in the main text on the left part of the screen.  When I click an item in the sidebar, the entire window scrolls, which causes the target title to scroll out of sight.  (if you try it you will understand what I mean).
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: try providing a jsfiddle so we can reproduce the issue

Comment: The link you've provided does not work!

Comment: link is corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can do something like:

```
$('#sidebar a').click(function () {
    $('#main').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

I've also added a scrolling animation because why not.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/4e0023g3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hyperlink for it, try using the `.scrollTop` in javascript. Something like this:-

```
document.getElementById("main").scrollTop = 200;
```

You can either hard-code the scrolling location like its done in this code or you can get the location of the particular element using `.offsetTop` and then assign it in the place of 200.